# Future.wait returning null

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class AdView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AdView({Key? key, required String id}) : super(key: key);
  final id = '2';
  @override
  _AdViewState createState() => _AdViewState();
}

class _AdViewState extends State<AdView> {
  final _adService = NewsService();

  Future<AdBanner?> futureAdd() async {
    _adService.getAds('2');
  }

  Future<Categories?> futureCatergoriess() async {
    _adService.getAllCategories();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureAdd();
    futureCatergoriess();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.wait([futureCatergoriess(), futureAdd()]),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final advertisements = snapshot.data![0];

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: advertisements!.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  //return bannerListTile(advertisements, index, context);
                  return const Text('index');
                });
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return NewsError(
                errorMessage: '${snapshot.hasError}',
              );
            }
            return const NewsLoading(
              text: 'Loading...',
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

snapshot.data![0]; returning null value. I tried already many versions ([1] or snapshot.data.data but I cannot call the results.

I am using future.wait first time. There is no problem if I use any of API with traditional Future.builder.

any help?

after the advice of @ChristopherMoore I modified the code but the main problem is still continue. This code gives as output:

```
index
index
```

modified code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([futureCatergoriess(), futureAdd()]),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final advertisements = snapshot.data!;

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: advertisements.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                //return bannerListTile(advertisements, index, context);
                return const Text('index');
              });
```

This original line gives this error:

`final advertisements = snapshot.data![0];`

`The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length The relevant error-causing widget was FutureBuilder<List<Object?>> lib/view/ad_view.dart:37`

Comment: `future: future,` future is undefined
`InitState()`
`final future = Future.wait([futureCatergoriess(), futureAdd()]);`

Comment: @gegentierversuche You functions `futureCatergoriess` and `futureAdd` don't have return statements. They will always return `null`. This is not directly related to `Future.wait`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore still getting null
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([futureCatergoriess(), futureAdd()]),

Comment: @gegentierversuche I don't understand the relevance of you the code you just commented. Please revisit my previous comment and make the necessary changes. If you problem persists, edit you question to reflect your latest attempt and provide a [MCVE].